# Magento 2 : Best Seller are not updated for imported order

Tags: magento2, best-seller, magento-cron, refresh-statistics

I have import orders and generate shipment and invoice, But our Statistics are not updated like **best seller, Most Viewed, Order Collection**, **Dashboard Graph**.

I have already tried with cron and refresh statistics so please don't suggest this type of solutions.

Comment: Have you try reindexing?

Comment: @PareshaU yes i have tried but no luck.

Comment: @PareshaU any other solutions please?

Comment: Can you try restarting server once. I had similar issue in the past for something else.

Comment: @LAW I can't because it is Magento Enterprise Cloud version. so not control by me.